# Tntfs.ko - How can I put it in an initrd file? Or load on boot?

Tags: linux, kernel-modules, initrd

I'm trying to load that specific module (for zenworks purposes), but I can't find the right command to put in my server boot. I tried `insmod` and `modprobe` commands, but I'm unsuccessful in doing that.
On the other hand, I think if I can put that module directly in the `initrd/lib/modules` folder, I think I don't need an additional command.

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: initrd is built of modules you have in your system. And it uses the same "insmod" to load modules, so if it fails for you, it will fail in initrd too. So you have to dig into your modprobe error for that specific module (is it exists?).

Comment: when i mount my share folder on client, inside of this folder i have tntfs.ko, so, the file exists but i cant load it after bash appear on client. Any ideas @tifssoft

Comment: apparently i've success with insmod command, i've tried insmod /path/filename, and now i can restore image. thx @tifssoft